# How to Print info on each page when subreport has more than one page data

Tags: reporting-services, subreport

I have a subreport in a ssrs main report (rdl) using ssrs 2012. The subreport starts on the middle of the page in the main report detail section. I have one group in main report, shows header info and passes one parameter to the subreport. The subreport spans across multiple pages however the report does not show the main report's column/row headers on subsequent pages until the new group starts.
Any ideas how to print header info on each page when subreport has more than one page data?
Thanks